# Append a sequence of bytes in a given encoding to CFMutableString

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a CFMutableString object to which I would like to append a sequence of bytes in a given  encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16,  UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, etc.)

The most efficient way which I have is:

```
CFStringRef tmp = CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, numBytes, encoding, NO, kCFAllocatorNull);
CFStringAppend(myMutableString, tmp);
CFRelease(tmp);
```

Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: Why aren't you using `NSMutableString*` and friends? Note that it'd make this pattern any fewer lines (well, the `CFRelease()` would go away), but it'd likely be lot easier to maintain/read?

Comment: Well, I should actually consider that. But it would be a lot of code to change. Maybe I will fix that first. Thx. I guess I was fearing that (I already started migrating a few classes). But it answers my question.

Comment: CF can be useful for certain esoteric cases, but -- generally -- sticking with NS* + ARC will reduce lines of code.

Comment: If you're using CF, this isn't really any ObjC question, it's just a C question…

Comment: By "most efficient" and "better", do you mean "less CPU time"? If not, what _do_ you mean? If so, is this actually a bottleneck, and what does the whole loop look like? (Obviously the most efficient way to append 10000 strings of different encodings into one big string may not be the most efficient way to append 10000 strings each to another string of the same encoding.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're actually asking about efficiency (as in CPU time), and that you actually do have a bottleneck in your string-building. I'll throw out some ideas in decreasing order of likeliness-to-be-useful.

Often you're appending a bunch of things into one big string, and you can cut the time by 20-50% by using `CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings` / `-[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:]`.

```
CFStringRef tmp = CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, numBytes, encoding, NO, kCFAllocatorNull);
CFStringAppend(myMutableString, tmp);
CFRelease(tmp);
```

…do this:

```
CFStringRef tmp = CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, numBytes, encoding, NO, kCFAllocatorNull);
CFArrayAppendValue(myMutableArray, tmp);
CFRelease(tmp);
// ... after you've finished accumulating everything
CFString *myString = CFStringCreateByCombiningStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, myMutableArray, kEmptyString);
```

Sometimes you know the size of the string you're going to end up with, and you can cut the time by a bit by using the right capacity in the initial call to `CFStringCreateMutable` /  `-[NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:]`. Of course this optimization isn't compatible with the array joining.

You can avoid some of the conversion costs—and, if you aren't using array joining, some temporary `CFString` creation costs.

Obviously, right-endian UTF-16 is the same thing as `CFString`'s "characters", so you can just use `CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy`. Or `CFStringAppendCharacters`.

For wrong-endian UTF-16, the "NoCopy" isn't helping, and may even hurt a bit. Also, it's possible that you can do something faster than a general-purpose converted by just byte-swapping to right-endian UTF-16, especially if you can do it in-place. I wouldn't *assume* this is faster (especially on large strings), but it's definitely worth trying and timing if this really is a bottleneck.

BOM-prefixed UTF-16 is one or the other, once you shift the pointer 2 bytes.

For UTF-8, again, the "NoCopy" isn't helping, and may hurt a bit. But you obviously do need to do a conversion. While you might be able to find/write a faster decoder than CF's, it seems a lot less likely than with wrong-endian UTF-16. But you can still skip the temporary string with `CFStringAppendCString`.

It's also possible, although again not that likely, that some other Unicode library like `iconv` or `icu` can beat CF by a big enough margin to be worth it. If so, get everything into right-endian UTF-16 first, then `CFStringCreateWithCharacters` (if using array join) or `CFStringAppendCharacters` (if not).

Then there's always tricks with allocators and refcounting. If you create a zone allocator for the string and array storage, and a do-nothing CFArrayCallbacks, you can build everything up with only a few malloc calls and almost no refcounting, just drop everything on the floor of the zones, and free them once you do the `componentsJoinedByString:` (which, of course, uses the default allocator).

Of course with some extra application knowledge, all kinds of things might be possible. To take a ridiculously obvious case, let's say you're appending a bunch of strings that are all hex encodings of 16-byte values. In that case, just allocate one big block of 32*n+1 `unichar`, "decode" your UTF by just copying (right-endian UTF-16), copying from the pointer offset by 1 byte (wrong-endian UTF-16), or alternating bytes with 0s (UTF-8), then do one big `CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy`.